# Is SMT version of Microsoft Translator still available?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I would like to use SMT version of Microsoft Translator in Azure to compare the out put with other engines, but is it still available? I have searched and found that SMT for personal use is available at http://www.bing.com/translator, but I wonder where we can use SMT for business use.

Best regards,
Naoki Notoya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft Translator Text API and Translator Speech API is available for personal and commercial use and both types of use would follow the Online Service Terms. Any user of the Translator API can use the SMT and NMT systems. See below for more information.

To read the terms, please go to the Microsoft Azure Legal Information page. You'll see a link to the Online Service Terms. When you open the Terms document, you can search for "Translator". The Microsoft Translator API is part of the Cognitive Services collection of APIs.

Microsoft Translator is SMT based service and all of our supported languages are SMT by default, except for Chinese and Hindi. These two languages are NMT by default.For 19 of the languages, you can choose to use SMT or NMT. Please see our Languages webpage for a list of the support languages. www.aka.ms/TranslatorLanguages

To invoke neural translations for the 19 languages, you use category=generalnn when you call the API. If you need to specifically call the Chinese or Hindi SMT systems, use the category=smt to access it.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your detailed answer. It resolved my question!